# "Invalid or corrupt skin" issue

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I usually join onto my little sister's server on Minecraft but ever since the game updated every skin including alex stops me from joining the game because apparently the skin is "invalid or corrupt". Please help, i want to keep playing Minecraft with my sister!!

Comment: What version of Minecraft PE?

Answer (score -1):

I've struggled with this myself even as a developer for plugins on minecraft java. I've recently wanted to test some stuff for myself on bedrock. I tried joining to see INVALID OR CORRUPT skin blaring out in my face. I tried many different things even as far as download mods. What I have figured out is that for whatever reason they changed either the font or file if skins in 1.13.1 and you must insert a skin for servers and mp to work. First download skin seed I have found as best. Then find a skin you like and export to minecraft pe. It will save the skin to your gallery, then go to mcpe. After go to your skins options then click edit then owned then finnaly import. You will click gallery then. You should see a random looking picture. Click it and exit. Now you can join servers and mp. Enjoy!

Comment: Can you be a little clearer and to-the-point? Also: would this actually work in this particular case? It seems the skins of one of the players is 'corrupted', and I don't think 'installing or creating new ones' is what they're after.

Answer (score -2):

When you have The new format for your skin ( Alex is the new format) you can't join other people's worlds! You must pick Steve ! If you have a custom skin and you put it on, it will ask you what one you want to use, Alex doesn't work, Steve is the one you must pick!